# My Lan Port making lots of Http requests when internet cable connected

Tags: networking, virus, malware, sniffing

i use internet in two ways. One is with wifi and other is with LAN cable. i use fiddler frequently for debugging my web project. Recently from past 2days, i found that when i connected LAN cable to my LAN port, it was continuously making lots of requests to different ad sites. No application is opened. Just fiddler is running. Still i saw lots of requests killing my net speed. Is this any virus or Malware or something ? 
i see ad.yieldads.com is the one making many requests. But when connected with wifi, its not happening. No requests are made automatically. Please advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like malware.  I wish there were easy instructions to fix it, but unfortunately there's not.

If you're using Windows, try several different products:

1. [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download)
2. [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)
3. [AVG](http://free.avg.com/us-en/homepage)

Hopefully one of those can help get rid of it.